# Kohana Startup Controller

Tags: kohana

I need to have a check for user validity on every page. Do I need a controller that checks this on every page or there is a simpler way of doing it? Do I need to create a base controller that is loaded each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it usually is done. Just extend a base class which checks the validity on the before method.

Here is an example:

`classes/controller/base.php`:

```
class Controller_Base extends Controller
{
    public function before()
    {
        //Do your checks here
    }
}
```

`classes/controller/welcome.php`:

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Base
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        //Do your normal thing here
    }
}
```

In the before method of the base controller, you can check the signed in user and permissions, and for example show an error message that they don't have access to that page.

Comment: Tried creating that but it didn't seem to overload or I need to set it as the startup controller in the bootstrap?

Comment: @Kenyana: I've added a small example.